# JasperReport GC overhead with huge report

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jvm, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report to generate a huge Excel report that might extend to 100k+ lines.

I first get my report lines then feed the jasperReport object with them. This is done without a problem.

The fillReport method takes some time but seems to be doing okay as well.

But when exporting my report I get huge memory usage and eventually my GC gets overloaded and my app crashes. For the record, this is the exception I'm getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintElement.writeObject(JRTemplatePrintElement.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.writeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSwapFileVirtualizer.pageOut(JRSwapFileVirtualizer.java:87)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:664)
```

I would like to know whether there's a way to optimize this use of memory and prevent this crash, specially when I need to be able to let my users generate these reports simultaneously. I have tried using swap files and virtualizers but this seems to be only optimizing the fillreport process.

This is the bit of code where I call my report generation function:

```
 List<LineaInformeFacturacionExcelCVO> listaLineasInformeFacturacionExcelCVO = new ArrayList<LineaInformeFacturacionExcelCVO>();
        List<LineaInformeFacturacionExcel> lineasInformeFacturacionExcel = lineaInformeFacturacionExcelDao.getLineasInformeFacturacionExcel(filtros);

getBytesInformeExcel(reportRealPath, parameters, listaLineasInformeFacturacionExcelCVO, true, jrExporterParameters);
```

This is the function itself:

```
    public byte[] getBytesInformeExcel(String reportRealPath, Map<String, Object> parameters, List<?> list, boolean virtualize, Map<JRExporterParameter, Object> jrExporterParameters) throws EmptyReportException, JRException {


    if (list != null && list.isEmpty()) {
                throw new EmptyReportException();
            }

              // Acordarse de pasarlo entre subrepors
            if (parameters == null)
                parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            Locale spainLocale = new Locale("es","ES");     
            TimeZone europeMadridTimezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid");                  
            parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, spainLocale);
            parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_TIME_ZONE, europeMadridTimezone);     

            JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = null;
            if (virtualize) {           
                virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(250, new JRSwapFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), 250, 250));
                parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);                    
            }

            parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, false);

            JasperReport jasperReport;

            byte[] reportBytes = null;
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;

            try {

                jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(reportRealPath);          

                Crono crono = new Crono();
                crono.startCrono();
                LOG.info("Iniciando JasperFillManager.fillReport() ");

                if (list == null) {
                    Connection connection = lineaInformeFacturacionDao.obtenerConnection();          
                    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);
                }
                else {
                    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
                }

                LOG.info("Fin JasperFillManager.fillReport() :" + crono.stopCrono() + " ms.");

                // Comprueba si el report está vacío.
                if (jasperPrint.getPages().isEmpty() || jasperPrint.getPages().get(0).getElements().isEmpty()) {
                       throw new EmptyReportException();
                }       

                ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                JRExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();;
                String formato = parametrosConfiguracion.getPropertie("informes.excel.formato");
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(formato)) {
                    if(formato.equals(parametrosConfiguracion.getPropertie("excel.formato.xls"))) {
                        exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                    } else if(formato.equals(parametrosConfiguracion.getPropertie("excel.formato.xlsx"))) {

                        exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
                    }
                }                        

                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);

                // Carga los parámetros por defecto
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);

                // Carga estos parámetros pasados como parámetro sobreescribiendo los por defecto 
                if (jrExporterParameters != null) {
                    exporter.setParameters(jrExporterParameters);
                    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                    exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, xlsReport);
                }            

                crono = new Crono();
                crono.startCrono();
                LOG.info("Iniciando exporter.exportReport() ");  
                exporter.exportReport();
                LOG.info("Fin exporter.exportReport() :" + crono.stopCrono() + " ms.");

                reportBytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();     


            }finally{
                if (virtualize) {
                    virtualizer.cleanup();
                }
            }

            return reportBytes;
}
```

And finally, if this is of any help, here's a screenshot of a memory profiling program at the moment of generating this report:

[image]

Crash happens at the second GC use peak.

Exporting directly to File with

```
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, new File("c://archivo.xlsx"));
```

instead of a ByteStream produces the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.writeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSwapFileVirtualizer.pageOut(JRSwapFileVirtualizer.java:87)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:664)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.evict(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:485)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.requestData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:630)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.ensureData(VirtualizableElementList.java:463)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.ensureDataAndTouch(VirtualizableElementList.java:432)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:283)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlockList.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:717)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:54)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGridLayout.createWrappers(JRGridLayout.java:922)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGridLayout.<init>(JRGridLayout.java:140)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:1000)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:983)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:650)
    at com.services.informes.InformesService.getBytesInformeExcel(InformesService.java:920)
    at com.services.informes.InformesService.getBytesInformeFacturacionExcel(InformesService.java:277)
    at com.controllers.InformesController.exportarInformeFacturacionExcel(InformesController.java:391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
```

This is the memory profiling in this case:
[image]

Comment: how big is your heap space ? if its stupidly small change it. Is there repor generation function called form within a loop ? Or recurisvely ? You need to reduce the number of new objects created.

Comment: It's set by Tomcat's default. I cannot reduce the number of objects; those are the number needed for the report... there should be a way to generate a report no matter how big it is, or shouldn't it?

Comment: IS the function called from with a loop ?

Comment: No, it's not. It's called once from the controller.

Comment: This is an old question, but a theory: I notice that "JRSwapFileVirtualizer.pageOut()" appears in your stacktraces. Can you tweak the virtualizer so that the threshold to moving data to disk is lowered? It could be that when the Virtualizer "kicks in" to move data onto the disk, it is already too late (you have an out-of-memory situation in your hands). Flush to disk sooner, and you might still have some free memory.